# php worried about time_out

Tags: php, time-limiting

hy
i had the problem "php time out" when i was unextract a zip file on the server, but this is a long time ago and i use an other server now.
my current script, should create some folders, create a file in this order and extract a zip file with pictures inside. then it creats a thumbnail for every picture.
The script is finisehd and it works great, But i'm afraid about the time out error.
i tested 10 pictures in one zip file. it works very fast. 
but if a user upload a package with 400 pictures, it will be need more time.
It should be possible to upload more than 400 pictures. thats the reason cause i create the zip-file upload.
is it possible to get an time-out error?
i don't know if i can us on this server

```
set_time_limit
```

if i can use it, i don't know how many time the script need.
mayby i'm worried about nothing

Comment: I suggest Gearman, you can upload the file and process it in an asynchronous way.

Comment: looks very difficult

Answer (score 1):

Create a `phpinfo.php` file an access it on your webserver. In this file you simply put:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

This will give you the current information about your server settings.
Find the parameter called `max_execution_time` which holds the parameter for how long a script can run.

If you fear that your scripts will take longer time than this, you can adjust the variable in multiple ways.

Via `.htaccess`:

```
php_value max_execution_time     10800
```

Via `PHP.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 10800
```

in `index.php`:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10800);
```

Comment: i have max_... 40
how likely is it, that i need more time??
is 40 a long time?
how long does it take to create 400 thumbnails and insert database entrys????

Comment: 40 is equal to 40 seconds. How long that takes, I have no idea. Test it ;)

Comment: when i test it with my internet and the time will be enough, other user which have a ot so fast internet get troubles

Answer (score 0):

Well in the php function where you are doing your stuff you can achieve this by using something like:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');
```

For time limit or memory limit increase.